# Shrink-wrap Objects Together?

Tags: modeling

I'm wondering if there is any quick way to shrinkwrap objects together. For example, creating five spheres inside of an object, then mushing them all together to look like this: [image: enter link description here]

Comment: are you planning to make an animation? like the object before and after?

Comment: maybe some answers here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78769/how-to-create-vacuum-packaging

Answer (score 5):

If you're attempting to recreate the reference image, look at Metaballs. They're mathematically based geometry that have pseudo-surface tension.