# Plastic wrap simulation in Blender

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

Does anybody know how to achieve such an effect? I use the lastest version of Blender, no problems with creating plastic material, but need some help with simulating these kind of folds on edges.[image: enter image descriptioenter image description heren here]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78769/how-to-create-vacuum-packaging https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/how-to-do-vaccuum-sealed-pack-modeling-in-blender/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with the Cloth brush in Sculpting mode. I got the result below with a single stroke, you probably need to tweak the brush settings and add separate brush strokes for better wrinkles.

[image]