# Wet cloth material on skin

Tags: materials, node-editor

I would like to know how to make wet cloth material on character? How to make folds of fabric that don't touch skin are white, and those areas that come into contact with skin are color of skin?

Here's example:
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78769/how-to-create-vacuum-packaging https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/how-to-do-vaccuum-sealed-pack-modeling-in-blender/

Comment: Ambient occlusion might be able to generate a useful mask

Comment: --- Duarte Farrajota Ramos ---
No no, I don't need packaging effect, but nodes for texture. I.e. how to make fabric adjacent to body have other color.

 --- Allen Simpson ---
I tried AO, but it doesn't quite give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a **wet clothes shader**, you need **a proximity mask** that defines where the fabric touches another object (e.g. body, floor). In the touching areas the fabric becomes quite transparent, in the other areas less so. (For realism, you also want to change the color slightly in these areas, and mix in some noise.)

[image: Suzanne with a wet blanket]<sup>No wet T-shirt contest but Suzanne! In the bottom left corner you see the reflection from clearcoat</sup>

Basically, **the shader** is just a *Mix* node feeding the *Alpha* input of the *Principled BSDF* node and *Clearcoat* set to 1.0. In the example, a [fabric texture](https://www.freepik.com/free-photo/simple-smooth-fabric-textured-background_17593140.htm) is used to get a better impression of the desired result.

The *Noise Texture* varies the transparency. This simulates that not all areas of the fabric are equally wet. You can do something similar to the *Roughness* value.

The *Color Ramp* nodes are used to adjust the transparency and color of the wet areas that are close to an object.

**For a good proximity map, combine a *Cloth* simulation with *Dynamic Paint* physics**. Then you can use the wet paint mask of the *Dynamic Paint* as a proximity mask.

[image: wet clothes shader setup]<sup>*meh! I forgot to mark the image count settings of the Image Texture* node but you can see it in the top left corner</sup>

For the *Canvas* settings, define a low *Dry* value like `5` to update the proximity mask quickly.

Make the *Brush* paint on *Proximity* with a low *Distance* of `0.1`, for example, but not too low because then it doesn't work.

[image: brush settings]

Now we have everything we need. But **there are a few things and pitfalls to consider**:

- **The Cloth Object**

  - will be the *canvas* for the *Dynamic Paint* and has the *Cloth* simulation
  - for *Cloth* simulation performance you want to keep the mesh as low-poly as possible but it must have enough geometry to create nice wrinkles.
  - a level 1 *Subdivision* modifier after the *Cloth* modifier will smooth the mesh
- **The Body and Floor Objects**

  - are *brushes* for the *Dynamic Paint*
  - they are also collision objects for the *Cloth* sim. If the body object is a high-poly object you can create and use a low-poly version for collision.
- ***Dynamic Paint*** can use vertex colors or a **baked *Image Sequence***.

  - since vertex colors require a high number of vertices and they will affect the *Cloth* simulation, it's better to go with a baked *Image Sequence*. This requires no extra geometry but a UV map.
  - the *Dynamic Paint* modifier should be below the *Subdivision* modifier to take advantage of the extra geometry to create smooth textures
- the ***Auto Refresh*** option of the *Image Sequence Texture* is only for frame changes and does not refresh automatically the images in memory as one might expect when the images are baked!

  - so the shader will still show you the outdated images even if they have been overwritten on disk.
  - **to update the baked images**, you need to re-open the first baked image (e.g. *wetpaint0001.png*) and then re-enter the number of images of the sequence (e.g. 100) for the *Image Texture* node in the shader editor.
- **Bake Order**

  - you need to bake the *Cloth* simulation first
  - then the *Image Texture Sequence* of *Dynamic Paint*
  - and finally, fix the *Image Sequence Texture* as described above in the shader editor
- **Troubleshooting**

  - if you have baked the physics, don't forget that you need to delete the cache and bake it again after you made changes
  - if it doesn't work, check the output folder if the images are baked correctly
  - if the wet effect looks blocky, it may help to increase the texture size. But keep in mind that this will slow down the bake process and requires more memory.
  - make sure you have the correct order of the modifiers (see screenshot below)
  - there are 4 different places where you must define **the end frame for your animation**. Make sure they have all the same value.

    - *End* setting in the *Timeline* editor where you press play
    - in the *Cloth* simulation cache settings
    - in the *Dynamic Paint > Canvas > Settings* section
    - and the *Image Texture* node setting in the *Shader Editor*

**Modifiers**

Cloth and Dynamic Paint > Canvas (the order is important). I forgot the ***Solidify*** modifier to give the fabric some thickness. Feel free to add it.
[image: canvas + cloth]

Dynamic Paint > Brushes:
[image: brushes]

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed explanation, it's very informative & useful!